# Is there a default focus and select behaviour following a JavaScript alert being clicked?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

As per the title, is there a default focus and select behaviour following a JavaScript alert being clicked?

The reason I ask is that I have a JavaScript function validating an asp.net text box in a web forms application. I added a JavaScript alert to the function to help with debugging and the behaviour seemed to change. When I clicked on the OK button of the alert it then set the focus to the field I was validating and selected the text.

I thought it must be something in my code causing this behaviour so I commented out all the instances where I was setting focus and select, but still saw the same behaviour. As soon as I removed the alert it went back to behaving as expected and no longer selected the data in the text box.

Does this sound like it could be related to the JavaScript alert or just something odd going on in my code?

Comment: Please show your code so that we can replicate the issue.

Comment: Also, since you are alerting for debug purposes, you might try console.log("here"); in your script instead of alert.  You can see the "console" in tools such as Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools.  In the least, it would let you know if alert was somehow interfering.  Also, console.log is a lot more powerful in terms of examining objects at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

There is auto focus in html5, but the issue here seems like different. If the alert is a custom alert functionality try to remove that and add window.alert() function instead. These are wild guesses, it would e great if you can post your code block here?